# validate username, password and email with php

Tags: php, validation, preg-replace, preg-match

I am working on validating username, pass and email with php. I need to be sure I get it right so nobody can bypass the login page.

This is the values:

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
$username=$_POST['uname'];
$passwd=$_POST['pass'];
$passwd2=$_POST['passcopy'];
```

So far I have email validation:

```
if(!(preg_match("/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/", $_POST['email'])))
    die(msg(0,"You haven't provided a valid email"));
```

password equal:

```
if ($passwd != $passwd2) {
die(msg(0,"Passwords are not equal"));
}
```

password length:

```
if ((strlen($passwd) < 8) || (strlen($passwd) > 16)) {
die(msg(0,"Your password must be between 8 and 16 characters. Please type in a longer password"));
}
```

I know I need to validate the username. I was thinking only lowercase a-z0-9 to avoid people making similar usernames?  Then password, what characters should I allow in a password?

PS. I still don't understand preg_match and ereg. If somebody could explain this `"/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+` and make a preg_match for my username and password validation it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the string `^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+` is a regular expression, that describes a pattern that you validate the email string against.

Let me break the different parts down for you.

`^` this indicates that the pattern should start matching at the beginning of the line.

`[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+` this part is composed of two sub parts, first `[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]` that describes a class of characters, and then a + that indicates that you want one or more of the previous class.

`[@]` matches exactly one `@` sign.

`[A-z0-9_\-]+` another class of characters with a `+` after that means that you want one or more of the characters that are in the class.

Answer (score 1):

```
"/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+/"// write same checking on same line

#1# ^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+
```

char have to be start with ( .a-z0-9_-+ ) one or more of previous char into []

```
#2# [@]
```

this char must not inputed /// put to trash not enter him

`#3# [A-z0-9_\-]+$// it should be ending with $char`

string contain char between (A-Z0-9_-) mean of sign plus is one or more of previous char
and $ is char have to be end with previous character in square bracket.

u can use simple regex is same as to yours previous..

`/^[A-z0-9_\-\+@]+$/` `// My regex script do same as your previous code`

hope it can help u

Answer (score 0):

> PS. I still don't understand preg_match and ereg. If somebody could explain this

It's a very bad example of how to check for a valid email address. Try google for better examples. Note that just because it matches a **good** regex does not mean that the person is receiving mail there - a far better approach if you need to validate an email address is to mail an activation URL or an initial password to the supplied address.

> make a preg_match for my username and password validation

erm, a lesson in regexes would take rather a long time - [try this](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565922570)

It really doesn't matter what the username (or password) contains as long as the combination is unique and you [handle the data properly](http://xkcd.com/327/)

C.

Answer (score 0):

[`preg_match`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [`ereg`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) are two ways of matching a string via a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). The `preg` functions use the PCRE (perl-compatible regular expression) engine and are the recommended regular expression functions for php; the `ereg` functions are deprecated now.

I won't go through explaining the pattern because it's covered in other answers, but if you want a really thorough regular expression tutorial (and free, to boot), check out the [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) on regular-expressions.info.

Answer (score 0):

Email validation:

```
if (filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)  == TRUE) {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
} else {
    echo "email error";
    die;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: 2 comments:
1) The `filter_var()` function returns the email address as a string, or `false`.  Comparing this to a bool `true` is rather redundant since the 'if()' statement is already testing for a truthy value. 
2) This validates using [RFC 822], which does not allow '+' symbols in the username part of the email address.